# Reset jupyter notebook shortcuts to default

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, jupyter-notebook, default, reset

I changed some shortcuts for my jupyter notebooks. Though, after all, I don't like my changes, anymore.

Is there a way to reset all shortcuts at once? Under "Help" -> "Edit Keyboard Shortcuts", I don't see this option. I only could go over all keys manually and change them back... If I even knew which I have changed...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no way to reset them. The easiest method I've found is to open up `~/.jupyter/nbconfig/notebook.json` and delete the entire `"keys"` scope. Make a backup of the file before touching it, of course. Here's mine:

```
{
  "load_extensions": {
    "collapsible_headings/main": true
  },
  "keys": {
    "command": {
      "bind": {
        "a,b,c": "jupyter-notebook:cut-cell-attachments"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then after (make sure to get rid of that comma):

```
{
  "load_extensions": {
    "collapsible_headings/main": true
  }
}
```

Save that file and reload Jupyter.

Comment: I deleted the entire file - because I did not have anything like extensions or so in it. That reseted it for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to previous answer, it is necessary to keep in the `json` format for the config.

If you clear it totally, please at least leaving a bracket pair {} so that there will be no error for future `nbextension` installation through `jupyter nbextension install`. Else, when perform installation, jupyter can't not read the format from the config correctly.

Correct Empty Config Format:

```
{
}
```